# Previous UILocalNotifications lost, when scheduling new ones, and between app launches

Tags: ios, iphone, uilocalnotification

I am scheduling UILocalNotifications. They are stored and work as expected. But once I schedule more UILocalNotification, the previously created ones are lost. And, all notifications are lost between launches of the app from Xcode 6.

I have 2 classes that manage different notification (create, cancel, etc.)

Here is the first one, the other one is pretty similiar and the error appears in both:

```
static NSCalendar *currentCalendar;

@implementation PBWurmProphylaxeNotificationsManager

+ (void)initialize{
currentCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
}

+(void)createAndScheduleNotificationWith:(NSDate *)fireDate withAlertBody:(NSString *)alertBody withUserInfo:(NSDictionary *)userInfo{
UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
notification.fireDate = fireDate;
notification.repeatInterval = NSYearCalendarUnit;
notification.alertBody = alertBody;
notification.hasAction = NO;
notification.userInfo = userInfo;
notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
}

+(void)enableWurmProphylaxeNotifications:(int)count{
// loop over the dogs array
NSArray *hunde = [self fetchHunde];
for (Hund *myDog in hunde) {
    [self enable:count WurmProphylaxeNotificationsForHund:myDog];
}
NSLog(@"[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications] count] %lu", (unsigned long)[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications] count]);
}

+(void)enable:(int)count WurmProphylaxeNotificationsForHund:(Hund *)myDog{
NSDate *day = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *myComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
int loops;
switch (count) {
    case 2:
        // schedule 6 notifications with time difference of 2 month and yearly repeatInterval
        [myComps setMonth:2];
        loops = 6;
        break;
    case 4:
        // schedule 3 notifications with time difference of 4 month and yearly repeatInterval
        [myComps setMonth:4];
        loops = 3;
        break;
    case 6:
        // schedule 2 notifications with time difference of 6 month and yearly repeatInterval
        [myComps setMonth:6];
        loops = 2;
        break;
    default:
        // schedule 3 notifications with time difference of 4 month and yearly repeatInterval
        [myComps setMonth:4];
        loops = 3;
        break;
}
NSMutableDictionary *userInfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[userInfo setValue:myDog.uuid forKey:KEY_DOG_UUID];
[userInfo setValue:@YES forKey:IS_WURM_PROPHYLAXE_NOTIFICATION];
NSString *alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Wurmprophylaxe für %@ fällig.", myDog.name];
for (int i = 0; i < loops; i++) {
    day = [currentCalendar dateByAddingComponents:myComps toDate:day options:0];
    [self createAndScheduleNotificationWith:day withAlertBody:alertBody withUserInfo:userInfo];
    }
}

+(void)disableWurmProphylaxeNotifications{
    NSArray *scheduledNotifications = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];
for (UILocalNotification *notification in scheduledNotifications) {
    NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.userInfo;
    if([userInfo valueForKey:IS_WURM_PROPHYLAXE_NOTIFICATION]){
        notification.userInfo = nil;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notification];
    }
}
NSLog(@"[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications] count] %lu", (unsigned long)[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications] count]);
}

+(void)disableWurmProphylaxeNotificationsForHund:(Hund *)myDog{
NSArray *scheduledNotifications = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];for (UILocalNotification *notification in scheduledNotifications) {
    NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.userInfo;
    if([userInfo valueForKey:IS_WURM_PROPHYLAXE_NOTIFICATION]){
        NSString *uuid = (NSString *)[userInfo valueForKey:KEY_DOG_UUID];
        if ([uuid isEqualToString:myDog.uuid]) {
            notification.userInfo = nil;
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notification];
        }
    }
    }

}

+(NSArray *)fetchHunde{
CoreDataHelper *cdh = [(AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] cdh];

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [cdh context];

NSFetchRequest  *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest  alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription  *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                                entityForName:@"Hund" inManagedObjectContext:[cdh context]];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSSortDescriptor  *sort1 = [[NSSortDescriptor  alloc]
                            initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];

NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(uuid != %@)", @"dog_unbekannt"];

[fetchRequest setPredicate:pred];

[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray  arrayWithObjects:sort1, nil]];

[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
return results;
}
@end
```

And here is the code which calls the methods of above class:

```
    // schedule notification if active
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([defaults boolForKey:WURM_PROPHYLAXE_ERINNERN]) {
        // schedule the notification as per user settings
        int count = [defaults integerForKey:KEY_TEST];
        [PBWurmProphylaxeNotificationsManager enable:count WurmProphylaxeNotificationsForHund:myDog];
    }
```

For debugging purposes, I am using the table view controller which displays this array:

```
_scheduledNotifications = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];
```

What is wrong? How can I efectively debug local notifications?